# I would like to have values from multiple textboxes added up and insert into final Textbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My file contains 106 frames, 62 textboxes and 183 Radio buttons which will insert a value into associated textbox.
Each text box is associated with 3 radio buttons
Each text box will take the value from a selected radio button.

My goal is to have all of the values from textbox1 thru textbox61 added up and insert that value into textbox62.

I have attached from my original file 4 frames with their radio buttons and textboxes.
Deff 7 Either prints frame or generates nameerror textbox2 not defined

I know this is well above my level and if I saw a piece of code I could move forward to the last stage of my project.
My next step will be to have a frame opened depending on the value in textbox62
Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("600x900")

def onclick1():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '2.83')

def onclick2():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '5.66')

def onclick3():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '8.49')

def onclick4():
    textbox2.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox2.insert('end', '8.83')

def onclick5():
    textbox2.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox2.insert('end', '17.66')

def onclick6():
    textbox2.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox2.insert('end', '26.49')

def onclick7():
    textbox2.get('1.0', 'end')
    textbox3.insert("end", frame2)
    #textbox3.insert("end", frame2, Textbox2.text)

button_var1 = tk.IntVar()
button_var2 = tk.IntVar()
button_var3 = tk.IntVar()
button_var4 = tk.IntVar()
button_var5 = tk.IntVar()
button_var6 = tk.IntVar()
button_var7 = tk.IntVar()

frame1 = Frame(root, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame3 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame4 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame4.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2,sticky="NW")

label = Label(frame2, text="Select # of LAV CNC 240 Units", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame3, text="Select # Of LAV CNC 500 Units", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame4, text="Total CFM Values", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")

textbox1 = Text(frame2, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=1)
textbox1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
textbox2 = Text(frame3, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=1)
textbox2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
textbox3 = Text(frame4, textbox1, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=30, height=1)
textbox3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

button1=Radiobutton(frame2, text="1 Unit ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick1)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button2=Radiobutton(frame2, text="2 Units ", variable=button_var2, command=onclick2)
button2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button3=Radiobutton(frame2, text="3 Units ", variable=button_var3, command=onclick3)
button3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button4=Radiobutton(frame3, text="1 Unit ", variable=button_var4, command=onclick4)
button4.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button5=Radiobutton(frame3, text="2 Units ", variable=button_var5, command=onclick5)
button5.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button6=Radiobutton(frame3, text="3 Units ", variable=button_var6, command=onclick6)
button6.grid(row=3, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button7=Radiobutton(frame4, text="Show Values ", variable=button_var7, command=onclick7)
button7.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should use same `IntVar` for `button1`, `button2` and `button3`.  Same for `button4`, `button5` and `button6` as well.

Comment: I understand now that I do not need multiple IntVar's. for my button. Back to my original question. Whenever a button or numerous buttons clicked to concaconate checkbox1 text thru checkbox61 text into textbox62. Eventually the the text value will will control which frame will depending on value.

Answer (score 1):

Grouped `Radiobuttons` need to be linked to the same `IntVar`.  It's probably easier to use `Labels` instead of `Texts`.  Code for a generic 2 group application below.  It uses `DoubleVars` to maintain the Label texts and allow easy summing of the Var fields.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
    
root = tk.Tk()
    
group1 = tk.IntVar()
group2 = tk.IntVar()
    
v0 = tk.DoubleVar( value = 0.0 )
v1 = tk.DoubleVar( value = 0.0 )
    
v_tot = tk.DoubleVar()
    
def do_sum():
    v_tot.set( v0.get() + v1.get() )
    
def do_group1():
    ix = group1.get()
    v0.set( { 1: 2.82, 2: 5.66, 3: 8.49 }[ix] )
    do_sum()
    
def do_group2():
    ix = group2.get()
    v1.set( { 1: 8.83, 2: 17.66, 3: 26.49 }[ix] )
    do_sum()
    
spacer = { 'padx': 3, 'pady': 3 }
    
# Group 1
r = 0
ttk.Label( root, text = 'Group 1  : ').grid( row = r, column = 0, **spacer )
ttk.Label( root, text = "", textvariable = v0 ).grid( row = r, column = 1 )
ttk.Radiobutton( root, text = 'Button 1', variable = group1, value = 1,
                     command = do_group1 ).grid( row = r, column = 2, **spacer )
ttk.Radiobutton( root, text = 'Button 2', variable = group1, value = 2,
                     command = do_group1 ).grid( row = r, column = 3, **spacer )
ttk.Radiobutton( root, text = 'Button 3', variable = group1, value = 3,
                     command = do_group1 ).grid( row = r, column = 4, **spacer )
    
# Group 2
r = 1
ttk.Label( root, text = 'Group 2  : ').grid( row = r, column = 0)
ttk.Label( root, text = "", textvariable = v1 ).grid( row = r, column = 1 )
ttk.Radiobutton( root, text = 'Button 1', variable = group2, value = 1,
                 command = do_group2 ).grid( row = r, column = 2, **spacer )
ttk.Radiobutton( root, text = 'Button 2', variable = group2, value = 2,
                 command = do_group2 ).grid( row = r, column = 3, **spacer )
ttk.Radiobutton( root, text = 'Button 3', variable = group2, value = 3,
                 command = do_group2 ).grid( row = r, column = 4, **spacer )
    
# Total
r = 3
ttk.Label( root, text = 'Total  : ').grid( row = r, column = 0)
ttk.Label( root, text = "", textvariable = v_tot ).grid( row = r, column = 1 )
    
root.mainloop()
```

**Following your comment below**
I've tried to do a minimum change to the code in the question and show a sum in frame3.  Does this answer your question?

`onclick7` could be executed by each `onclickX` to keep a running total and not require a Total button at all.

It should be possible to reduce the number of `onclickX` to use the value returned in the `IntVar`s.  This would make future maintenance easier.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
    
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("600x900")
    
# text_boxes_to_sum = [ textbox1, textbox2 ]
    
def onclick1():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '2.83')
    
def onclick2():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '5.66')
    
def onclick3():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '8.49')
    
def onclick4():
    textbox2.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox2.insert('end', '8.83')
    
def onclick5():
    textbox2.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox2.insert('end', '17.66')
    
def onclick6():
    textbox2.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox2.insert('end', '26.49')
    
# *********   Changes   **************
    
def to_float( string ):
    # Return the float from a valid string or zero if invalid.
    try: 
        return float( string )
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0
    
def onclick7():
    tot = 0.0
    for box in text_boxes_to_sum:
        # text_boxes_to_sum is defined below after textbox3
        v = box.get( '1.0', 'end' )
        tot += to_float( v )
    textbox3.delete( '1.0', 'end' )
    textbox3.insert( 'end', str(tot) )
    
# ************************************
    
button_var1 = tk.IntVar()
button_var2 = tk.IntVar()
button_var3 = tk.IntVar()
    
frame1 = Frame(root, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame3 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame4 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame4.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2,sticky="NW")
    
label = Label(frame2, text="Select # of LAV CNC 240 Units", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame3, text="Select # Of LAV CNC 500 Units", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame4, text="Total CFM Values", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
    
textbox1 = Text(frame2, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=1)
textbox1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
textbox2 = Text(frame3, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=1)
textbox2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
textbox3 = Text(frame4, textbox1, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=30, height=1)
textbox3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
    
text_boxes_to_sum = [ textbox1, textbox2 ]  
# Used in on_click7 but can't be created until the textboxes are defined.
    
button1=Radiobutton(frame2, text="1 Unit ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick1, value = 0 )
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button2=Radiobutton(frame2, text="2 Units ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick2, value = 1 )
button2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button3=Radiobutton(frame2, text="3 Units ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick3, value = 2 )
button3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button4=Radiobutton(frame3, text="1 Unit ", variable=button_var2, command=onclick4, value = 1 )
button4.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button5=Radiobutton(frame3, text="2 Units ", variable=button_var2, command=onclick5, value = 2 )
button5.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button6=Radiobutton(frame3, text="3 Units ", variable=button_var2, command=onclick6, value= 3 )
button6.grid(row=3, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button7=Radiobutton(frame4, text="Show Values ", variable=button_var3, command=onclick7, value = 0 )
button7.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Tis. I did not see your answer until after I posted my last comment. I like the way it adds everything up. I just need to figure out how to get sum value into final textbox

Comment: Unfortunately if I understand correctly this is a function that will only run in the root frame. I am working with frames that are gridded into the root frame Do I have any other options other then moving all of my data into the root. this would take months and I would loose the visual affect. Also can rows in the root be hidden until asked for. It has taken me 6 month to get this far.

Comment: There's no reason the functions are limited by what frame the widgets are in.  In my example the three 'groups' can be in one frame each without changing the function logic.  As you're using `grid` it's not too difficult to hide and show frames or widgets.  To sum the content of the text widgets you'd need to iterate across them, convert to reals and sum.  Convert the sum to a string and place the results in the text widget.

Comment: @Bruce Hagen I've added a second option in the answer above.  With minimum changes to the code in your question to get a total.

Comment: AWSOME!!! You guys at OS are great. I am now 1 step away from completing my PI file.